# mysql errno 150 when creating foreign key

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'm getting errno 150 and can't figure out why. I've read a million other answers that say you must have an index set up on the parent column and I do so i'm not sure why i'm still getting this error.

Parent table indexes:

```
mysql> show indexes from plans;
+-------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| plans |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | plan_id     | A         |          86 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| plans |          0 | plan_id_UNIQUE |            1 | plan_id     | A         |          86 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| plans |          1 | plan_id        |            1 | plan_id     | A         |          86 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Child Table indexes:

```
mysql> show indexes from promos;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| promos |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | promo_id    | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| promos |          1 | plan_id  |            1 | plan_id     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Error:

```
mysql> alter table promos add foreign key (plan_id) references plans (plan_id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dev.#sql-2ce_599a' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: do the data types of the child and parent columns match exactly?

Comment: Enable then disable foreign keys and in between try to alter. `set foreign_key_checks = 0; alter ...;
set foreign_key_checks = 1;`. Also make sure you are using InnoDB

Comment: Compare your script with the following in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/991b2)

Comment: yes, the data types are the same...
primary:
| plan_id               | varchar(50)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    ||
foreign:
| plan_id     | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    ||

Comment: @LoganMurphy, I tried disabling foreign key checks and got the same error.

Comment: @WilliamChiquito, your script works but I'd rather fix this without having to drop the plans table as it already has data.

Comment: Please post the actual create statements. You get them by querying `show create table table_name`.

Comment: @fancyPants ... see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb664e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the same collation and character set for both columns.

this works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f917